# MSVS 2017 problems with c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I download it the MSVS 2017 , but when I installed and I tried to create a simple hello world in c++ , and I couldnt compile because it seems Microsoft removed the option win32api .

my fresh install I checked the universal Windows platform , and Desktop development c++

[image: install]

when I click project winapi is gone

[image: new-project]

I tried to expand the universal tab , but nothing interesting 
[[image: windows universal[2]]

how can I fix this error?

Comment: This might simply be a problem with how you ran the installer. Try reopening the Visual Studio Installer and making sure that "Desktop development with C++" really is selected, and ensure that you actually run the installer again to apply changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking "Desktop Development with C++", on the right hand side pane there is a sub-feature check list. Make sure you are selecting the Windows SDK versions you want to target, along with Visual C++ MFC for x86 and x64, and Visual C++ ATL for x86 and x64:

[image: Visual Studio Installer: Desktop Development with C++]